# Change Field to Capitalize Each Word under Details

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reporting, is there a formula or method to change a field that shows in `Details` from coming back in `ALL CAPS` to just capitalizing `Each Word` instead?

So instead of coming out as:

NAME

```
PRESLEY, ELVIS
LENNON, JOHN
SINATRA, FRANK
```

I wanted the results to come out as:

Name

```
Presley, Elvis
Lennon, John
Sinatra, Frank
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

ProperCase([fieldname])

Comment: Just got it. I add it as a formula! Thanks ^